# Set Scale for Decimals stored in a String Array in an Object

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a string array in an object which is storing a decimal value.

```
String [] array = "12345.123456789";
```

I want it to be formatted as `12345.1234`

I tried it with the following but resulted in a Number Format Exception.

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(array.toString()).setScale( 4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP );
array = ( Object )value.toString();
```

I am new to java so can anyone please help...

Comment: compiler will give an error for this `String [] array = "12345.123456789";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String [] array = "12345.123456789";` is not a valid statement - either it is a String or an array, so you need to choose between the following two statements:

```
String s = "12345.123456789"; //a string
String[] array = {"12345.123456789"}; //an array
```

If you use the first form, you can round it with:

```
BigDecimal rounded = new BigDecimal(s).setScale( 4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP );
String roundedStr = rounded.toString();
```

If you use the second form, you can use this:

```
BigDecimal rounded = new BigDecimal(array[0]).setScale( 4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP );
String roundedStr = rounded.toString();
```

Comment: If you round `12345.123456789` half up you get `12345.1235` instead of `12345.1234`.

Comment: Thanks @assylias . Now how do I add `12345.1235` back to `array`.

Comment: @DebajyotiDas As mentioned in the comment above, you need to use `BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN` as a rounding mode. To put the value back in the array just assign it: `array[0] = roundedStr;`.

Answer (score 3):

```
       String [] array = {"12345.123456789"};
        StringBuilder numbers = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            BigDecimal digits = new BigDecimal(array[i]).setScale( 4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP );
            numbers.append(digits.toString());

        }

        System.out.println(numbers);
```

Comment: Hi Subodh... Now how do I add this `12345.1234` to `array`